# How to convert commonly used html tags correctly to plaintext format?

Tags: html, tags, markdown, plaintext

This original text is from the following URL. `<h1>Effect of strontium on Nd doped Ba<sub>1-</sub><i><sub>x</sub></i> Sr <i><sub>x</sub></i> Ce<sub>0.65</sub>Zr<sub>0.25</sub>Nd<sub>0.1</sub>O<sub>3-</sub><i><sub>δ</sub></i> proton conductor as an electrolyte for solid oxide fuel cells.</h1>`

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28203457

If you google "Effect of strontium on Nd doped", you will see something like [image]. Ce0.65Zr0.25Nd0.1O3-δ is collapsed. Is there a way to convert such kind of strings in a plaintext format yet still maintain the html tagging info. (Maybe markdown is a good plaintext like format for this purpose?)

Answer (score -1):

Google has a character limit between 50-60 characters (some characters are wider that's why it's a range)

From a SEO standpoint you could simplify your `title` tag to be 'Effect of strontium on Nd as an electrolyte' (I know nothing about your content so excuse me if that's completely inaccurate) and use a `h1` tag which would contain your full title.

That way you get the best of both worlds, you'll have a nice search result that isn't truncated and you're telling Google what the important information is.

Comment: My question is not about google. It is about how to convert html to plaintext with essential format information maintained.